# Envirenment id in gitlab as build number

Tags: gitlab, yaml

How to get the environment id in gitlab yaml as a build number?

I tried $CI_ENVIRONMENT_ID but this does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in variable for the `envronment id`. But you could get with this [API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/environments.html#list-environments):

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/environments?name=review%2Ffix-foo"
```